# How to reset form Java Spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to reset form after moving from "Success Registration Page" back

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String homePage(Model model) {
        return "index";
    }
    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String showForm(Model model) {
        Student user = new Student();
        model.addAttribute("student",user);
        return "registration";
    }
    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String submitForm(@Valid Student student, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        System.out.println(student.toString());
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        } else {
            return "registration_success";
        }
    }
}
```

I have "Go back" Button on /registration_success

I tried `document.getElementById('FullName').value = '';` but nothing happens. After clicking "Enter" I can't reset my form.. Why and how to fix it?

```
public Student(String fullName, LocalDate birthday, String faculty, String cathedra, String group, long year) {
            this.FullName = fullName;
            this.birthday = birthday;
            this.faculty = faculty;
            this.cathedra = cathedra;
            this.group = group;
            this.year = year;
        }



<form class="registration_fields" th:action="@{/registration}" commandName="cmd" th:object="${student}" th:method="POST" id="reg_form">
        <label>Full Name:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{FullName}"> <div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('FullName')}" th:errors="*{FullName}"></div>
        <label>Birthday Date:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{birthday}"/><div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('birthday')}" th:errors="*{birthday}"></div>
        <label>Faculty:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{faculty}"><br><div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('faculty')}" th:errors="*{faculty}"></div>
        <label>Cathedra:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{cathedra}"><br><div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('cathedra')}" th:errors="*{cathedra}"></div>
        <label>Group:</label><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{group}"><br><div class="alert alert-warning" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('group')}" th:errors="*{group}"></div>
        <label style="display: none;">Years:</label><input style="display: none;" class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{year}"><br>
        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" value="Register">
        <input type="button"  class="btn btn-danger" value="Reset">
    </form>
```

Comment: document.getElementById('FullName').value = ''; this line should work fine, are you sure you are running your script after generating whole page and that id FullName is id of your textarea ? What do you get after typing in console document.getElementById('FullName').value?

Answer (score 2):

Your form has an id `reg_form`

This will reset the whole form `document.getElementById("reg_form").reset();`